# error: The type name `var' could not be found

Tags: vala

I'm trying to build a fresh clone of Granite's master branch, on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera, but I'm getting these errors:

```
../lib/Widgets/SwitchModelButton.vala:65.9-65.19: error: The type name `var' could not be found
        unowned var description_style_context = description_label.get_style_context ();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../lib/Widgets/Utils.vala:298.5-298.15: error: The type name `var' could not be found
    unowned var gtk_settings = Gtk.Settings.get_default ();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Dependency wise I did not get warning from meson:

```
meson build --prefix=/usr
The Meson build system
Version: 0.49.2
Source dir: /home/peteruithoven/Projects/elementary/granite
Build dir: /home/peteruithoven/Projects/elementary/granite/build
Build type: native build
Project name: granite
Project version: 6.1.0
Native C compiler: cc (gcc 7.5.0 "cc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0")
Native Vala compiler: valac (valac 0.40.25)
Build machine cpu family: x86_64
Build machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Dependency gio-unix-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4
Dependency gee-0.8 found: YES 0.20.2
Dependency gio-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4
Dependency glib-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4
Dependency gobject-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4
Dependency gtk+-3.0 found: YES 3.22.30
Configuring Config.vala using configuration
Library m found: YES
Library posix found: YES
Program g-ir-compiler found: YES (/usr/bin/g-ir-compiler)
Program /home/peteruithoven/Projects/elementary/granite/meson/post_install.py found: YES (/home/peteruithoven/Projects/elementary/granite/meson/post_install.py)
Build targets in project: 10
Found ninja-1.8.2 at /usr/bin/ninja
```

Is a newer vala compiler required or something like that? Can I even build the latest granite on v5?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a newer vala computer was indeed needed, probably 0.48:
https://github.com/elementary/granite/issues/492#issuecomment-830612898